# Angular 2+ update value in select after call modal

Tags: typescript, angular2-forms, two-way-binding

I have a problem with setting the default value to the select element after it is added to the modal window. Below is a piece of code that will probably help to understand what is wrong.
 This is my SELECT

```
  <select 
   [disabled]="electricalItem.equipmentType.length == 0"
   id="selectedEquipmentType"
   class="form-control selectForOpenModal"
   [(ngModel)]="electricalItem.selectedEquipmentType"
   name="selectedEquipmentType"
  >
   <option
    *ngFor="let currentEquipmentType of electricalItem.equipmentType" 
    [ngValue]="currentEquipmentType"
    [selected]="currentEquipmentType==electricalItem.selectedEquipmentType"
   >
    {{currentEquipmentType}}
   </option>
  </select>
  <button
   type="button"
   class="btn btn-outline-secondary btnPlus fa fa-plus"
   data-toggle="tooltip"
   data-placement="top"
   title="Add new item"
   (click)="equipmentTypeModal.showAddModal()"
  ></button>
  <button
   type="button"
   class="btn btn-outline-secondary btnMinus fa fa-minus"
   data-toggle="tooltip"
   data-placement="top"
   title="Drop selected item"
   (click)="equipmentTypeModal.showDropModal(dropElementFlag)"
   [disabled]="electricalItem.equipmentType.length == 0"
  ></button>
```

I call the modal window as follows

```
<app-electricals-modal
 [dataValue]="electricalItem.equipmentType" 
 [selectedValue]="electricalItem.selectedEquipmentType" 
 [title]="equipmentType" #equipmentTypeModal>
</app-electricals-modal>
```

My code for adding an item to the collection after some experiments looks like this.

```
  @Input() dataValue;@Input() selectedValue;@Input() title: string;
```

And push method

```
 public addItem(itenEl: string){
  this.dataValue.push(itenEl);
  this.selectedValue = itenEl;
  this.visible = false;
  setTimeout(() => this.visible = false, 300);
  this.itenElement = null;}
```

So it's time to showcase the results.
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4g5s.png)

And After [i get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZ8XO.png)

So if you now how fix this i will be grateful. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Can you create a plunker or stackblitz demo for debug

Comment: Remove `[selected]="currentEquipmentType==electricalItem.selectedEquipmentType"`. The source of truth is the ngModel. If the ngModel (i.e. electricalItem.selectedEquipmentType) is the currentEquipmentType, then the option is selected. So you need to make sure that electricalItem.selectedEquipmentType is indeed `===` to one of the currentEquipmentType.

Comment: @JBNizet Removing the [selected] element does not give the result (((the attempt to add (ngModelChange) = "onChange ($ event)" is called only when the drop-down list is activated, maybe I did not quite understand you. Can you give an example of your vision for solving this issue?

Comment: To solve the issue, you need to make sure that electricalItem.selectedEquipmentType is indeed === to one of the currentEquipmentType. You have posted a lot of irrelevant code, but not the code that initializes the array `electricalItem.equipmentType`, and the value `electricalItem.selectedEquipmentType`. That's what matters: the latter is supposed to be an element of the former.

Comment: @JBNizet do you can show me some example?